# C# Application: Get Network Shares On Another Computer

Tags: c#, networking

First of all, apologies if this doesn't make sense, and/or it has already been asked (although searching didn't find anything).

I have an application which sets default printers for our end users but I would like to expand it by also making it able to install printers from a remote machine as well.

What I need to do is on Form_Load populate a Combo Box with all network shares from the print server.

I am shooting in the dark and am wondering if anyone can shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works.

This isnt my code originally but I cant remember where it came from.

```
using System.Management;

private void btnGetPrinters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Use the ObjectQuery to get the list of configured printers.

    ObjectQuery oquery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

    ManagementObjectSearcher mosearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery);

    ManagementObjectCollection moc = mosearcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
        PropertyDataCollection pdc = mo.Properties;

        foreach (System.Management.PropertyData pd in pdc)
        {
            if ((bool)mo["Network"])
            {
                cmbPrinters.Items.Add(mo[pd.Name]);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```